# Mongoose "setter" acting like "getter"?

Tags: mongodb, node.js, mongoose

Using Mongoose with MongoDB and Node.js

Previously I had my UserSchema defined like this:

```
var UserSchema = new Schema({
  username:     { type: String, unique: true },
  password:     String,
  email:        { type: Email, unique: true, validate:/^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/ }
});
```

When my User was created I encrypted the password.  Then I found out about "[setters](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/getters-setters.html)" and I changed my UserSchema to this:

```
var UserSchema = new Schema({
  username:     { type: String, unique: true },
  password:     { type:String, set:encryption.Encrypt },
  email:        { type: Email, unique: true, validate:/^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/ }
});
```

I have made no other changes (that I can remember) and when trying to log in with a User I discovered that my password was wrong.  When I looked at the data, the encrypted password sent back from the database was different than the one stored in the database.  If I take out the "setter" from my UserSchema, it looks correct.

Now my problem with this is that "setters" are described like this:

> As you can see above, setters allow you to transform the data before
> it gets to the raw mongodb document and is set as a value on an actual
> key.

To me, it looks like this Setter is actually acting like a Getter and transforming the data as it comes BACK from the database.

Am I completely misunderstanding this?

Comment: I'm not sure what's going on, but have you tried comparing user.password to user.doc.password (which should be the raw mongo document)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This was actually a bug in Mongoose that has since been fixed in Mongoose 2.0